# How to delete uncommitted blocks in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, put

I am trying to do some automation using [`PUT Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) in Azure Blob Storage.

My questions are:

**Q1.  Do uncommitted blocks reserve space?**

**Q2. How can I delete the uncommitted blocks?**

- The method I am using now is to get all the uncommitted blocks by [`GET Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list).
- Commit the uncommitted blocks using [`PUT Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) and then delete the blob
  altogether to free up space.

Is there any better way of deleting uncommitted blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way of deleting uncommitted blocks?

As such there's no direct way of deleting uncommitted blocks. If you do not do anything with those blocks, they are automatically deleted after 7 days.

One possible solution would be to call `Put Block List` with empty or a single uncommitted block and then delete the blob. That way all uncommitted blocks will be deleted.

Other option would be to create another blob with the same name using `Put Blob` operation. Since your intention is to delete uncommitted blocks, you can create this blob as a zero byte blob.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the PowerShell code from this link [Troubleshooting InvalidBlock 'The specified block list is invalid’ based errors](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-invalidblock-the-specified-block-list-is-invalid/ba-p/1870350) to clear uncommitted blocks in Azure Blob Storage. PowerShell code copied below;

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param(

  #Please enter storage account name

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)] [string] $StorageAccountName,

  #Please enter Shared Access Signature <SAS token > generated with the permissions <ss=b;srt=sco;sp=rwldc>

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)] [string] $SharedAccessSignature,

  #Please enter storage Container name

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)] [string] $ContainerName ,

  #Please enter Blob name

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)] [string] $Blobname

   )

 

# below rest API helps in getting the uncommitted block List

$Blob = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/"+$ContainerName+"/"+$Blobname+"$SharedAccessSignature&comp=blocklist&blocklisttype=uncommitted"

$Blob

$listfileURI =  Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $Blob

 

$FilesystemName = $listfileURI.Content

$String=$FilesystemName -replace 'ï»¿' , ''

$String | Select-Xml –Xpath “/BlockList/UncommittedBlocks/Block”|Select-Object -Expand Node

$Count=$String.Count

 

#deletion of the blob & uncommitted block

if($Count.Count -gt 0)

{

$delete= "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/"+$ContainerName+"/"+$Blobname+"$SharedAccessSignature"

$listfileURI1 =  Invoke-WebRequest -Method Delete -Uri $delete

$FilesystemName1 = $listfileURI1.StatusCode

Write-Host "Deletion has been successfully , API returned status code " $FilesystemName1

}

Write-Host "Check if the uncommitted block are still present"

 

Try

{

$Blobcheck = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/"+$ContainerName+"/"+$Blobname+"$SharedAccessSignature&comp=blocklist&blocklisttype=uncommitted"

$listfileURI2 =  Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $Blobcheck

}

catch{

#$err=$_.Exception

    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__

    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription

}

Write-Host "With the above error message we can confirm that the uncommitted blocks and their respective blob has been deleted"

Write-Host "Name and size of uncommitted block that has been deleted are as below"
```